# Oracle SQL Update statement with value generated in subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I am trying to write an update statement to insert a value that's calculated in a subquery, and having limited success.

The statement I've tried so far is:

```
update intuit.men_doc doc1
set doc1.doc_udf5 = (select
substr(doc.doc_dtyc, instr(doc.doc_dtyc, 'GAPP-', 2)+5 )||'_'||row_number() over(partition by 
doc.doc_dtyc order by doc.doc_cret) docDeleteId
from
intuit.men_doc doc 
where
doc.doc_dtyc != 'DM-GAPP-SFUL'
and doc.doc_dtyc like 'DM-GAPP%'
and doc.doc_cred >= '01/Oct/2017' and doc.doc_cred < '01/Oct/2018'
and doc1.doc_code = doc.doc_code
)
```

Which gives mes the following error message

```
ERROR: Error 1427 was encountered whilst running the SQL command. (-3)
Error -3 running SQL : ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I don't have much experience with UPDATE statements, so any advice on how I can rewrite this so that I can update a few thousand records at once would be appreciated.

EDIT: Adding example data

Example data:

```
MEN_DOC
DOC_CODE    DOC_DTYC    DOC_UDF5    DOC_CRED
123456A     CV                      08/Nov/2017
456789B     CV                      11/Jan/2018
789123C     CV                      15/Feb/2018
123987B     TRAN                    01/Dec/2017
```

How I want the data to look once the script is run

```
MEN_DOC
DOC_CODE    DOC_DTYC    DOC_UDF5    DOC_CRED
123456A     CV          CV_1        08/Nov/2017
456789B     CV          CV_2        11/Jan/2018
789123C     CV          CV_3        15/Feb/2018
123987B     TRAN        TRAN_1      01/Dec/2017
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `LIMIT 1` (and ORDER BY) to subquery, for example...

Comment: Your select statement is returning more than 1 matched record, so it does not know what value to update with.  Run your select statement independently and make sure it returns only 1 matched record.

Comment: Sample data with expected result will be helpfull. Do you want to update each row separately or should teh subquery calculate the new value from selveral rows?

Comment: Have updated with example data

Comment: Is there any chance having multiple DOC_CODE for the specified criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `row_number()`, which suggests that you expect the subquery to return more than one row.  The inequality on `doc_code` supports this interpretation.

Just change the `row_number()` to `count(*)`, so you have an aggregation which will always return one row and get the sequential count you want:

```
update intuit.men_doc doc1
    set doc1.doc_udf5 = (select substr(doc.doc_dtyc, instr(doc.doc_dtyc, 'GAPP-', 2)+5 ) ||'_'|| count(*) docDeleteId
                         from intuit.men_doc doc 
                         where doc.doc_dtyc <> 'DM-GAPP-SFUL' and
                               doc.doc_dtyc like 'DM-GAPP%' and
                               doc.doc_cred >= date '2017-10-01' and
                               doc.doc_cred < date '2018-10-01' and
                               doc1.doc_code = doc.doc_code
                         );
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Not sure if I explained what I'm trying to do well enough. I have thousands of records in the men_doc table with a few different options for values in doc_dtyc. I wanted to store a unique sequence number in doc_udf5 that is partitioned by doc_dtyc. Eg where DOC_DTYC = 'CV', DOC_UDF5 = 'CV_1', and then 'CV_2' for the next record and so on...

Answer (score 0):

You can use your `select` as source table in `merge`, like here:

```
merge into men_doc tgt
using (select doc_code, 
              doc_dtyc||'_'||row_number() over (partition by doc_dtyc order by doc_cred) as calc
         from men_doc) src
on (tgt.doc_code = src.doc_code)
when matched then update set tgt.doc_udf5 = src.calc;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d10fcd1ca2507e7457c3efa9a97ce913)</sup>**

I assumed that doc_code is unique.